# How to find union between array of first value in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a set of array like this:

```
[["1","2"],["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","5"]]
```

I want to find the union of first values like

`["1","2"],["1","3"]` matches so i need to create new array like `["1","2,3"]`

so the resulting array will be like

```
[["1","2,3"],["2","3,5"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Like most problems in Ruby, the Enumerable module does the job:

```
input = [["1","2"],["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","5"]]

result = input.group_by do |item|
  # Group by first element
  item[0]
end.collect do |key, items|
  # Compose into new format
  [
    key,
    items.collect do |item|
      item[1]
    end.join(',')
  ]
end

puts result.inspect
# => [["1", "2,3"], ["2", "3,5"]]
```

The `group_by` method comes in very handy when aggregating things like this, and `collect` is great for rewriting how the elements appear.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not a true union for a true union of each 2 it would be:

```
data = [["1","2"],["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","5"]]
data.each_slice(2).map{|a,b| a | b.to_a }
#=> [["1","2","3"],["2","3","5"]]
```

Here is a very simple solution that modifies this concept to fit your needs:

```
data = [["1","2"],["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","5"]]
data.each_slice(2).map do |a,b|
  unified = (a | b.to_a)
  [unified.shift,unified.join(',')]
end
#=>  [["1", "2,3"], ["2", "3,5"]]
```

Added `to_a` to piped variable `b` in the event that there are an uneven number of arrays. eg.

```
 data = [["1","2"],["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","5"],["4","7"]]
 data.each_slice(2).map do |a,b|
   unified = (a | b.to_a)
   [unified.shift,unified.join(',')]
 end
 #=>  [["1", "2,3"], ["2", "3,5"], ["4","7"]]
```

If you meant that you want this to happen regardless of order then this will work but will destroy the `data` object

```
data.group_by(&:shift).map{|k,v| [k,v.flatten.join(',')]}
#=>  [["1", "2,3"], ["2", "3,5"], ["4","7"]]
```

Non destructively you could call

```
data.map(&:dup).group_by(&:shift).map{|k,v| [k,v.flatten.join(',')]}
#=>  [["1", "2,3"], ["2", "3,5"], ["4","7"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |(i,*rest),h| (h[i] ||= []).concat(rest) }
     .map { |i,rest| [i, rest.join(',')] }
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr1 = [["1","2"],["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","5"]]
doit(arr1)
  #=> [["1", "2,3"], ["2", "3,5"]]

arr2 = [["1","2","6"],["2","7"],["1","3"],["2","3","9","4","cat"]]
doit(arr2)
  # => [["1", "2,6,3"], ["2", "7,3,9,4,cat"]]
```

**Explanation**

For `arr1` above, we obtain:

```
enum = arr1.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["1", "2"], ["1", "3"], ["2", "3"],
  #                  ["2", "5"]]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert `enum` to an array see its elements:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[["1", "2"], {}], [["1", "3"], {}],
  #    [["2", "3"], {}], [["2", "5"], {}]]
```

These elements will be passed into the block, and assigned to the block variables, by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which will invoke [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each). The first of these elements (`[["1", "2"], {}]`) can be obtained by invoking [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) on `enum`:

```
(i,*rest),h = enum.next
     #=> [["1", "2"], {}] 
i    #=> "1" 
rest #=> ["2"] 
h    #=> {}
```

We then execute:

```
(h[i] ||= []).concat(rest)
  #=> (h["1"] ||= []).concat(["2"]) 
  #=> (nil ||= []).concat(["2"]) 
  #=> [].concat(["2"]) 
  #=> ["2"]
```

`each` then passes the next element of `enum` to the block:

```
(i,*rest),h = enum.next
  #=> [["1", "3"], {"1"=>["2"]}]
i    #=> "1" 
rest #=> ["3"] 
h    #=> {"1"=>["2"]}
(h[i] ||= []).concat(rest)
  #=> (h["1"] ||= []).concat(["3"]) 
  #=> (["2"] ||= []).concat(["3"]) 
  #=> ["2"].concat(["3"]) 
  #=> ["2", "3"]
```

After passing the last two elements of `enum` into the block, we obtain:

```
h=> {"1"=>["2", "3"], "2"=>["3", "5"]}
```

`map` creates an enumerator:

```
enum_h = h.each
  #=> > #<Enumerator: {"1"=>["2", "3"]}:each>
```

and calls `Enumerator#each` (which calls [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each)) to pass each element of `enum_h` into the block:

```
i, rest = enum_h.next 
  #=> ["1", ["2", "3"]]
```

then computes:

```
[i, rest.join(',')] 
  #=> ["1", ["2", "3"].join(',')]
  #=> ["1", "2,3"]
```

The other element of `enum_h` is processed similarly.

Comment: As always very thorough explanation and a creative solution as well.